# Can active directory alone support single sign on in shiro without using CAS?

Tags: java, active-directory, shiro

I have mapped an active directory in shiro which authenticates user properly. 
    Now I want to do a single sign on within two web application which is mapped with the same active directory.
    Is it possible to do a single sign on without using CAS approach?
    Below is the code that I have written,

```
**shiro.ini file**
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /Login.xhtml
authc.usernameParam = USERNAME
authc.passwordParam = USERPASSWORD
authc.rememberMeParam = rememberMe
user.loginUrl = /Login.xhtml

activeDirectoryRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryRealm
activeDirectoryRealm.systemUsername = testuser
activeDirectoryRealm.systemPassword = password
activeDirectoryRealm.searchBase = DC=XXX,DC=XXXXXX,DC=com
activeDirectoryRealm.url = ldap://XXX.XXXXXX.com:389

[users]

[urls]
/Login.xhtml = authc
/** = authc
/Login.xhtml = anon
/app/** = user

I would be very grateful, if any of you could help me with this. Thanks in advance
```